# Change the rangeslider's starting point videojs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js, rangeslider

I am using videojs in my react application. I have added rangeslider to it. There is a button near my video player which triggers the rangeslider to show up on the video player. Every thing works fine, but the rangeslider's start arrow is not at the point (time) where I clicked the button. The starting button is always at time 0:0. What I want is: say the video is playing at the current time 30:00 seconds and I clicked the show button, then rangeslider should show it's starting arrow at 30 sec only and not at o sec. I can get my current time of videojs player and pass it to rangeslider.js plugin, but I don't know where to pass it.

This is my rangeslider.js (I know it's a long code but i don't know which part of it to use to achieve the result)

```
//----------------Load Plugin----------------//
(function () {
    var videojsAddClass = function (element, className) {
        element.classList.add(className);
    };
    var videojsRemoveClass = function (element, className) {
        element.classList.remove(className);
    };
    var videojsFindPosition = function (element) {
        return element.getBoundingClientRect();
    };

    var videojsRound = function (n, precision) {
        return parseFloat(n.toFixed(precision));
    };
    var videojsFormatTime = function (totalSeconds) {
        var minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60).toFixed(0);
        var seconds = (totalSeconds % 60).toFixed(0);

        if (seconds.length === 1) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        return minutes + ':' + seconds;
    };
    var videojsBlockTextSelection = function () {
        // TODO
    };

//-- Load RangeSlider plugin in videojs
    function RangeSlider_(options) {
        var player = this;

        player.rangeslider = new RangeSlider(player, options);

        //When the DOM and the video media is loaded
        function initialVideoFinished(event) {
            var plugin = player.rangeslider;
            //All components will be initialize after they have been loaded by videojs
            for (var index in plugin.components) {
                plugin.components[index].init_();
            }

            if (plugin.options.hidden)
                plugin.hide(); //Hide the Range Slider

            if (plugin.options.locked)
                plugin.lock(); //Lock the Range Slider

            if (plugin.options.panel == false)
                plugin.hidePanel(); //Hide the second Panel

            if (plugin.options.controlTime == false)
                plugin.hidecontrolTime(); //Hide the control time panel

            plugin._reset();
            player.trigger('loadedRangeSlider'); //Let know if the Range Slider DOM is ready
        }
        if (player.techName == 'Youtube') {
            //Detect youtube problems
            player.one('error', function (e) {
                switch (player.error) {
                    case 2:
                        alert("The request contains an invalid parameter value. For example, this error occurs if you specify a video ID that does not have 11 characters, or if the video ID contains invalid characters, such as exclamation points or asterisks.");
                    case 5:
                        alert("The requested content cannot be played in an HTML5 player or another error related to the HTML5 player has occurred.");
                    case 100:
                        alert("The video requested was not found. This error occurs when a video has been removed (for any reason) or has been marked as private.");
                        break;
                    case 101:
                        alert("The owner of the requested video does not allow it to be played in embedded players.");
                        break;
                    case 150:
                        alert("The owner of the requested video does not allow it to be played in embedded players.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("Unknown Error");
                        break;
                }
            });
            player.on('firstplay', initialVideoFinished);
        } else {
            player.one('playing', initialVideoFinished);
        }

    }
    videojs.plugin('rangeslider', RangeSlider_);



//-- Plugin
    function RangeSlider(player, options) {
        var player = player || this;

        this.player = player;

        this.components = {}; // holds any custom components we add to the player

        options = options || {}; // plugin options

        if (!options.hasOwnProperty('locked'))
            options.locked = false; // lock slider handles

        if (!options.hasOwnProperty('hidden'))
            options.hidden = true; // hide slider handles

        if (!options.hasOwnProperty('panel'))
            options.panel = true; // Show Second Panel

        if (!options.hasOwnProperty('controlTime'))
            options.controlTime = true; // Show Control Time to set the arrows in the edition

        this.options = options;

        this.init();
    }

//-- Methods
    RangeSlider.prototype = {
        /*Constructor*/
        init: function () {
            var player = this.player || {};

            this.updatePrecision = 3;

            //position in second of the arrows
            this.start = 0;
            this.end = 0;

            //components of the plugin
            var controlBar = player.controlBar;
            var seekBar = controlBar.progressControl.seekBar;
            this.components.RSTimeBar = seekBar.RSTimeBar;
            this.components.ControlTimePanel = controlBar.ControlTimePanel;

            //Save local component
            this.rstb = this.components.RSTimeBar;
            this.box = this.components.SeekRSBar = this.rstb.SeekRSBar;
            this.bar = this.components.SelectionBar = this.box.SelectionBar;
            this.left = this.components.SelectionBarLeft = this.box.SelectionBarLeft;
            this.right = this.components.SelectionBarRight = this.box.SelectionBarRight;
            this.tp = this.components.TimePanel = this.box.TimePanel;
            this.tpl = this.components.TimePanelLeft = this.tp.TimePanelLeft;
            this.tpr = this.components.TimePanelRight = this.tp.TimePanelRight;
            this.ctp = this.components.ControlTimePanel;
            this.ctpl = this.components.ControlTimePanelLeft = this.ctp.ControlTimePanelLeft;
            this.ctpr = this.components.ControlTimePanelRight = this.ctp.ControlTimePanelRight;

        },

        show: function () {
            this.options.hidden = false;
            if (typeof this.rstb != 'undefined') {
                this.rstb.show();
                if (this.options.controlTime)
                    this.showcontrolTime();
            }
        },
        hide: function () {
            this.options.hidden = true;
            if (typeof this.rstb != 'undefined') {
                this.rstb.hide();
                this.ctp.hide();
            }
        },
        showPanel: function () {
            this.options.panel = true;
            if (typeof this.tp != 'undefined')
                videojsRemoveClass(this.tp.el_, 'disable');
        },

        showcontrolTime: function () {
            this.options.controlTime = true;
            if (typeof this.ctp != 'undefined')
                this.ctp.show();
        },
        hidecontrolTime: function () {
            this.options.controlTime = false;
            if (typeof this.ctp != 'undefined')
                this.ctp.hide();
        },
        setValue: function (index, seconds, writeControlTime) {
            //index = 0 for the left Arrow and 1 for the right Arrow. Value in seconds
            var writeControlTime = typeof writeControlTime != 'undefined' ? writeControlTime : true;

            var percent = this._percent(seconds);
            var isValidIndex = (index === 0 || index === 1);
            var isChangeable = !this.locked;
            if (isChangeable && isValidIndex)
                this.box.setPosition(index, percent, writeControlTime);
        },
        setValues: function (start, end, writeControlTime) {
            //index = 0 for the left Arrow and 1 for the right Arrow. Value in seconds
            var writeControlTime = typeof writeControlTime != 'undefined' ? writeControlTime : true;

            this._reset();

            this._setValuesLocked(start, end, writeControlTime);
        },
        getValues: function () { //get values in seconds
            var values = {}, start, end;
            start = this.start || this._getArrowValue(0);
            end = this.end || this._getArrowValue(1);
            return {start: start, end: end};
        },


        _getArrowValue: function (index) {
            var index = index || 0;
            var duration = this.player.duration();

            duration = typeof duration == 'undefined' ? 0 : duration;

            var percentage = this[index === 0 ? "left" : "right"].el_.style.left.replace("%", "");
            if (percentage == "")
                percentage = index === 0 ? 0 : 100;

            return videojsRound(this._seconds(percentage / 100), this.updatePrecision - 1);
        },
        _percent: function (seconds) {
            var duration = this.player.duration();
            if (isNaN(duration)) {
                return 0;
            }
            return Math.min(1, Math.max(0, seconds / duration));
        },
        _seconds: function (percent) {
            var duration = this.player.duration();
            if (isNaN(duration)) {
                return 0;
            }
            return Math.min(duration, Math.max(0, percent * duration));
        },
        _reset: function () {
            var duration = this.player.duration();
            this.tpl.el_.style.left = '0%';
            this.tpr.el_.style.left = '100%';
            this._setValuesLocked(0, duration);
        },
        _setValuesLocked: function (start, end, writeControlTime) {
            var triggerSliderChange = typeof writeControlTime != 'undefined';
            var writeControlTime = typeof writeControlTime != 'undefined' ? writeControlTime : true;
            if (this.options.locked) {
                this.unlock();//It is unlocked to change the bar position. In the end it will return the value.
                this.setValue(0, start, writeControlTime);
                this.setValue(1, end, writeControlTime);
                this.lock();
            } else {
                this.setValue(0, start, writeControlTime);
                this.setValue(1, end, writeControlTime);
            }

            // Trigger slider change
            if (triggerSliderChange) {
                this._triggerSliderChange();
            }
        },
        _checkControlTime: function (index, TextInput, timeOld) {
            var h = TextInput[0],
                m = TextInput[1],
                s = TextInput[2],
                newHour = h.value,
                newMin = m.value,
                newSec = s.value,
                obj, objNew, objOld;
            index = index || 0;

            if (newHour != timeOld[0]) {
                obj = h;
                objNew = newHour;
                objOld = timeOld[0];
            } else if (newMin != timeOld[1]) {
                obj = m;
                objNew = newMin;
                objOld = timeOld[1];
            } else if (newSec != timeOld[2]) {
                obj = s;
                objNew = newSec;
                objOld = timeOld[2];
            } else {
                return false;
            }

            var duration = this.player.duration() || 0,
                durationSel;

            var intRegex = /^\d+$/;//check if the objNew is an integer
            if (!intRegex.test(objNew) || objNew > 60) {
                objNew = objNew == "" ? "" : objOld;
            }

            newHour = newHour == "" ? 0 : newHour;
            newMin = newMin == "" ? 0 : newMin;
            newSec = newSec == "" ? 0 : newSec;

            durationSel = videojs.TextTrack.prototype.parseCueTime(newHour + ":" + newMin + ":" + newSec);
            if (durationSel > duration) {
                obj.value = objOld;
                obj.style.border = "1px solid red";
            } else {
                obj.value = objNew;
                h.style.border = m.style.border = s.style.border = "1px solid transparent";
                this.setValue(index, durationSel, false);

                // Trigger slider change
                this._triggerSliderChange();
            }
            if (index === 1) {
                var oldTimeLeft = this.ctpl.el_.children,
                    durationSelLeft = videojs.TextTrack.prototype.parseCueTime(oldTimeLeft[0].value + ":" + oldTimeLeft[1].value + ":" + oldTimeLeft[2].value);
                if (durationSel < durationSelLeft) {
                    obj.style.border = "1px solid red";
                }
            } else {

                var oldTimeRight = this.ctpr.el_.children,
                    durationSelRight = videojs.TextTrack.prototype.parseCueTime(oldTimeRight[0].value + ":" + oldTimeRight[1].value + ":" + oldTimeRight[2].value);
                if (durationSel > durationSelRight) {
                    obj.style.border = "1px solid red";
                }
            }
        },
        _triggerSliderChange: function () {
            this.player.trigger("sliderchange");
        }
    };


//----------------Public Functions----------------//

//-- Public Functions added to video-js

    var videojsPlayer = videojs.getComponent('Player');

//Lock the Slider bar and it will not be possible to change the arrow positions
    videojsPlayer.prototype.lockSlider = function () {
        return this.rangeslider.lock();
    };

//Unlock the Slider bar and it will be possible to change the arrow positions
    videojsPlayer.prototype.unlockSlider = function () {
        return this.rangeslider.unlock();
    };

//Show the Slider Bar Component
    videojsPlayer.prototype.showSlider = function () {
        return this.rangeslider.show();
    };

//Hide the Slider Bar Component
    videojsPlayer.prototype.hideSlider = function () {
        return this.rangeslider.hide();
    };

//Show the Panel with the seconds of the selection
    videojsPlayer.prototype.showSliderPanel = function () {
        return this.rangeslider.showPanel();
    };

//Hide the Panel with the seconds of the selection
    videojsPlayer.prototype.hideSliderPanel = function () {
        return this.rangeslider.hidePanel();
    };


//Show the control Time to edit the position of the arrows
    videojsPlayer.prototype.showControlTime = function () {
        return this.rangeslider.showcontrolTime();
    };

//Hide the control Time to edit the position of the arrows
    videojsPlayer.prototype.hideControlTime = function () {
        return this.rangeslider.hidecontrolTime();
    };

//Set a Value in second for both arrows
    videojsPlayer.prototype.setValueSlider = function (start, end) {
        return this.rangeslider.setValues(start, end);
    };

//The video will be played in a selected section
    videojsPlayer.prototype.playBetween = function (start, end) {
        return this.rangeslider.playBetween(start, end);
    };

//The video will loop between to values
    videojsPlayer.prototype.loopBetween = function (start, end) {
        return this.rangeslider.loop(start, end);
    };

//Set a Value in second for the arrows
    videojsPlayer.prototype.getValueSlider = function () {
        return this.rangeslider.getValues();
    };



//----------------Create new Components----------------//

//--Charge the new Component into videojs
    var videojsSeekBar = videojs.getComponent('SeekBar');
    videojsSeekBar.prototype.options_.children.push('RSTimeBar'); //Range Slider Time Bar

    var videojsControlBar = videojs.getComponent('ControlBar');
    videojsControlBar.prototype.options_.children.push('ControlTimePanel'); //Panel with the time of the range slider



//-- Design the new components

    var videojsComponent = videojs.getComponent('Component');

    /**
     * Range Slider Time Bar
     * @param {videojs.Player|Object} player
     * @param {Object=} options
     * @constructor
     */
    var videojsRSTimeBar = videojs.extend(videojsComponent, {
        /** @constructor */
        constructor: function (player, options) {
            videojsComponent.call(this, player, options);
        }
    });

    videojsRSTimeBar.prototype.init_ = function () {
        this.rs = this.player_.rangeslider;
    };

    videojsRSTimeBar.prototype.options_ = {
        children: {
            'SeekRSBar': {}
        }
    };

    videojsRSTimeBar.prototype.createEl = function () {
        return videojsComponent.prototype.createEl.call(this, 'div', {
            className: 'vjs-timebar-RS',
            innerHTML: ''
        });
    };

    videojs.registerComponent('RSTimeBar', videojsRSTimeBar);

    /**
     * Seek Range Slider Bar and holder for the selection bars
     * @param {videojs.Player|Object} player
     * @param {Object=} options
     * @constructor
     */
    var videojsSeekRSBar = videojs.extend(videojsSeekBar, {
        /** @constructor */
        constructor: function (player, options) {
            videojsComponent.call(this, player, options);
            this.on('mousedown', this.onMouseDown);
            this.on('touchstart', this.onMouseDown);
        }
    });

    videojsSeekRSBar.prototype.init_ = function () {
        this.rs = this.player_.rangeslider;
    };

    videojsSeekRSBar.prototype.options_ = {
        children: {
            'SelectionBar': {},
            'SelectionBarLeft': {},
            'SelectionBarRight': {},
            'TimePanel': {},
        }
    };

    videojsSeekRSBar.prototype.createEl = function () {
        return videojsComponent.prototype.createEl.call(this, 'div', {
            className: 'vjs-rangeslider-holder'
        });
    };


    videojsSeekRSBar.prototype.onMouseDown = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        videojsBlockTextSelection();

        if (!this.rs.options.locked) {
            this.on(document, "mousemove", videojs.bind(this, this.onMouseMove));
            this.on(document, "mouseup", videojs.bind(this, this.onMouseUp));
            this.on(document, "touchmove", videojs.bind(this, this.onMouseMove));
            this.on(document, "touchend", videojs.bind(this, this.onMouseUp));

        }
    };

    videojsSeekRSBar.prototype.onMouseUp = function (event) {
        this.off(document, "mousemove", videojs.bind(this, this.onMouseMove), false);
        this.off(document, "mouseup", videojs.bind(this, this.onMouseUp), false);
        this.off(document, "touchmove", videojs.bind(this, this.onMouseMove), false);
        this.off(document, "touchend", videojs.bind(this, this.onMouseUp), false);

    };

    videojsSeekRSBar.prototype.onMouseMove = function (event) {
        var left = this.calculateDistance(event);

        if (this.rs.left.pressed)
            this.setPosition(0, left);
        else if (this.rs.right.pressed)
            this.setPosition(1, left);

        //Fix a problem with the presition in the display time
        var ctd = this.player_.controlBar.currentTimeDisplay;
        ctd.contentEl_.innerHTML = '<span class="vjs-control-text">' + ctd.localize('Current Time') + '</span>' + videojsFormatTime(this.rs._seconds(left), this.player_.duration());

        // Trigger slider change
        if (this.rs.left.pressed || this.rs.right.pressed) {
            this.rs._triggerSliderChange();
        }
    };

    videojsSeekRSBar.prototype.setPosition = function (index, left, writeControlTime) {
        var writeControlTime = typeof writeControlTime != 'undefined' ? writeControlTime : true;
        //index = 0 for left side, index = 1 for right side
        var index = index || 0;

        // Position shouldn't change when handle is locked
        if (this.rs.options.locked)
            return false;

        // Check for invalid position
        if (isNaN(left))
            return false;

        // Check index between 0 and 1
        if (!(index === 0 || index === 1))
            return false;

        // Alias
        var ObjLeft = this.rs.left.el_,
            ObjRight = this.rs.right.el_,
            Obj = this.rs[index === 0 ? 'left' : 'right'].el_,
            tpr = this.rs.tpr.el_,
            tpl = this.rs.tpl.el_,
            bar = this.rs.bar,
            ctp = this.rs[index === 0 ? 'ctpl' : 'ctpr'].el_;

        //Check if left arrow is passing the right arrow
        if ((index === 0 ? bar.updateLeft(left) : bar.updateRight(left))) {
            Obj.style.left = (left * 100) + '%';
            index === 0 ? bar.updateLeft(left) : bar.updateRight(left);

            this.rs[index === 0 ? 'start' : 'end'] = this.rs._seconds(left);

            //Fix the problem  when you press the button and the two arrow are underhand
            //left.zIndex = 10 and right.zIndex=20. This is always less in this case:
            if (index === 0) {
                if ((left) >= 0.9)
                    ObjLeft.style.zIndex = 25;
                else
                    ObjLeft.style.zIndex = 10;
            }

            //-- Panel
            var TimeText = videojsFormatTime(this.rs._seconds(left)),
                tplTextLegth = tpl.children[0].innerHTML.length;
            var MaxP, MinP, MaxDisP;
            if (tplTextLegth <= 4) //0:00
                MaxDisP = this.player_.isFullScreen ? 3.25 : 6.5;
            else if (tplTextLegth <= 5)//00:00
                MaxDisP = this.player_.isFullScreen ? 4 : 8;
            else//0:00:00
                MaxDisP = this.player_.isFullScreen ? 5 : 10;
            if (TimeText.length <= 4) { //0:00
                MaxP = this.player_.isFullScreen ? 97 : 93;
                MinP = this.player_.isFullScreen ? 0.1 : 0.5;
            } else if (TimeText.length <= 5) {//00:00
                MaxP = this.player_.isFullScreen ? 96 : 92;
                MinP = this.player_.isFullScreen ? 0.1 : 0.5;
            } else {//0:00:00
                MaxP = this.player_.isFullScreen ? 95 : 91;
                MinP = this.player_.isFullScreen ? 0.1 : 0.5;
            }

            if (index === 0) {
                tpl.style.left = Math.max(MinP, Math.min(MaxP, (left * 100 - MaxDisP / 2))) + '%';

                if ((tpr.style.left.replace("%", "") - tpl.style.left.replace("%", "")) <= MaxDisP)
                    tpl.style.left = Math.max(MinP, Math.min(MaxP, tpr.style.left.replace("%", "") - MaxDisP)) + '%';
                tpl.children[0].innerHTML = TimeText;
            } else {
                tpr.style.left = Math.max(MinP, Math.min(MaxP, (left * 100 - MaxDisP / 2))) + '%';

                if (((tpr.style.left.replace("%", "") || 100) - tpl.style.left.replace("%", "")) <= MaxDisP)
                    tpr.style.left = Math.max(MinP, Math.min(MaxP, tpl.style.left.replace("%", "") - 0 + MaxDisP)) + '%';
                tpr.children[0].innerHTML = TimeText;
            }
            //-- Control Time
            if (writeControlTime) {
                var time = TimeText.split(":"),
                    h, m, s;
                if (time.length == 2) {
                    h = 0;
                    m = time[0];
                    s = time[1];
                } else {
                    h = time[0];
                    m = time[1];
                    s = time[2];
                }
                ctp.children[0].value = h;
                ctp.children[1].value = m;
                ctp.children[2].value = s;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    videojs.registerComponent('SeekRSBar', videojsSeekRSBar);


    /**
     * This is the bar with the selection of the RangeSlider
     * @param {videojs.Player|Object} player
     * @param {Object=} options
     * @constructor
     */
    var videojsSelectionBar = videojs.extend(videojsComponent, {
        /** @constructor */
        constructor: function (player, options) {
            videojsComponent.call(this, player, options);
            this.on('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);
            this.on('touchend', this.onMouseUp);
            this.fired = false;
        }
    });

    videojsSelectionBar.prototype.init_ = function () {
        this.rs = this.player_.rangeslider;
    };

    videojsSelectionBar.prototype.createEl = function () {
        return videojsComponent.prototype.createEl.call(this, 'div', {
            className: 'vjs-selectionbar-RS'
        });
    };



    videojsControlTimePanelRight.prototype.init_ = function () {
        this.rs = this.player_.rangeslider;
        this.timeOld = {};
    };

    videojsControlTimePanelRight.prototype.createEl = function () {
        return videojsComponent.prototype.createEl.call(this, 'div', {
            className: 'vjs-controltimepanel-right-RS',
            innerHTML: 'End: <input type="text" id="controltimepanel" maxlength="2" value="00"/>:<input type="text" id="controltimepanel" maxlength="2" value="00"/>:<input type="text" id="controltimepanel" maxlength="2" value="00"/>'
        });
    };

    videojsControlTimePanelRight.prototype.onKeyDown = function (event) {
        this.timeOld[0] = this.el_.children[0].value;
        this.timeOld[1] = this.el_.children[1].value;
        this.timeOld[2] = this.el_.children[2].value;
    };

    videojsControlTimePanelRight.prototype.onKeyUp = function (event) {
        this.rs._checkControlTime(1, this.el_.children, this.timeOld);
    };

    videojs.registerComponent('ControlTimePanelRight', videojsControlTimePanelRight);
})();
```

And this is how rangeslider looks everytime it shows up

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
video.currentTime
```

But it looks like rangeslider is using

```
e.currentPoint
```

Comment: Please do not put a signature in your posts.  You can put that stuff in your profile

Comment: Don't use [signatures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), especially not ones containing links. They can be perceived as spam.